# Deduce a parameter pack from specific member of all pack elements

Tags: c++11, variadic-templates

I'm guessing this is rather simple, just can't figure out how to do it - Assuming each type passed in as a parameter has a member typedef called 't', how could I make of tuple of the member?

```
#include <tuple>

template <typename T>
struct A{
  typedef T t;
};

template <typename ...Ts>
struct B{
  std::tuple<Ts::t...> ts; // I want a tuple of Ts::t type...
};

int main()
{
  B<A<int>,A<float>> b;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: try `typename Ts::t...` instead of `Ts::t...`.

Comment: That worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters of the class template [`std::tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) are types.

`Ts::t` is a [`dependent name`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name).

To declare that a dependent name is a type, you have to use the `typename` keyword before it.

Now you know why `typename Ts::t...` works and `Ts::t...` does not.